# jQuery for navbar not working properly?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar and some jQuery for it, but I am not sure why it doesn't work as it should.

Currently I can have only my NEW and ACTIVE links highlighted, the others never get highlighted.
Can someone help?

Here is the script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $('ul.nav.navbar-nav').find('a[href="' + location.pathname +'"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Tha navbar :

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("NEW", "Create", "Todoes")</li>
                        <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("ALL", "Index", "Todoes")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("ACTIVE", "Active", "Todoes")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("COMPLETED", "Completed", "Todoes")</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Just a quick thing you could shorten the code in the `$('li').each()` to simply `$('.navbar li').removeClass('active')`

Comment: I thinks this still doesn't solve her problem, mate :)

Comment: not 100% on what her problem is, but if she's working on her code, that piece is remarkably redundant.

Comment: As far as I understand only two of her navbar links get highlighted when clicked. The other's don't get highlighted. Too bad i suck at jQuery :)

Comment: @op, when are you trying to add the active classes? When a link is clicked or when the page is loaded? I ask because your code as it is now only runs one time when the page loads. You'd need to add another set of instructions on a link click to change the classes.

Comment: I am trying to add the active class on both ocasions. When the page is loaded I want to have a default view loaded, and when a link is clicked I want to change the active class to that link and then highlight it. Cuurently the highlighting work only for the NEW and ACTIVE links, which is weird.